# Confusion between adjective and participle

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Consider the three sentences: 1. The experienced pain is acute. 2. Experienced candidates are invited to apply. 3. This candidate is experienced in all phases of SDLC.

In sentence 1, what is actually meant is: "the pain that is experienced" and not, repeat not, "pain having experience". In sentences 2 and 3, what is meant is: "candidates having experience".

In sentence 1, the word 'experienced' does not work as an adjective but works as a participle. In sentences 2 and 3, the word essentially functions as an adjective.

However, the Stanford POS-Tagger does exactly the opposite: it tags the word as "JJ" in sentence 1 and "VBN" in sentences 2 and 3.

The problem seems to arise mainly because the word 'experience' in English is both a noun and a verb.

Comment: So, there is a bug in the tagger, and understandable and explainable one. What sort of help do you think we can provide? Bear in mind, the authors of the code are unlikely to read your post here. Maybe you should raise an issue at the software's support site.

Comment: OK, noted. Thank you.